# line integral in scalar field with magnitude and without magnitude

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have two different definitions of a line integral in a scalar field:

One textbook says this:

$\int \limits_CF(\vec{r})~ds=\int \limits_{t_1}^{t_0} F\Big(\vec{r}(t)\Big)~\begin{vmatrix}\frac{d \vec{r}}{dt}\end{vmatrix}~dt$

Another textbook says this: (see picture attached)

$\int \limits_C F(r)d\vec{r}= \int \limits_{t_0}^{t_1} F\Big(\vec{r}(t)\Big)\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}dt$

What's the difference between them?  are they the same or slightly different things?

This version has line integral with out taking magnitude:

[image: example of later case]

Comment: Are you sure the first one is not $\int_{\mathcal{C}} F(\vec{r})\cdot d\vec{r} = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}F(\vec{r}(t))\cdot\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}dt$?

Comment: $F(\vec{r})$ is a scalar field...it returns a scalar, even though it takes a vector $\vec{r}$.  It wouldn't make sense to take the dot product of a scalar an a vector $d\vec{r}$.

Comment: No problem with line integral in vector field... I'm just curious about line integral in scalar field... wondering why there are two different version of it... one with a magnitude $\begin{vmatrix}\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\end{vmatrix}$ and the other without....

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/line-integrals-for-scalar-functions-articles/a/line-integrals-in-a-scalar-field